Elfutils library forward declaration error
I'm currently working in C++ with the elfutils library and I'm struggling with something that should be obvious.
Here is a MCVE that shows my problem:
file.cpp
struct Elf64_Sym;

#include <elf.h>

Of course in the complete code, the forward declaration is done in a .hpp file and the <elf.h> include is done in a .cpp file but this small example reproduce the exact same issue. You can try to compile it using the following command line g++ file.cpp and you will receive the following error:
In file included from /usr/include/libelf.h:36,
                 from file.cpp:3:
/usr/include/elf.h:538:3: error: conflicting declaration 'typedef struct Elf64_Sym Elf64_Sym'
  538 | } Elf64_Sym;
      |   ^~~~~~~~~
file.cpp:1:8: note: previous declaration as 'struct Elf64_Sym'
    1 | struct Elf64_Sym;
      |        ^~~~~~~~~

This compile fine with gcc (so in C) but not with g++ (so in C++).
Do you have a solution that would allow a forward declaration of the Elf64_Sym structure in C++?
And for completeness sake here is the definition of this struct in <elf.h>:
typedef struct
{
  Elf64_Word    st_name;        /* Symbol name (string tbl index) */
  unsigned char st_info;        /* Symbol type and binding */
  unsigned char st_other;       /* Symbol visibility */
  Elf64_Section st_shndx;       /* Section index */
  Elf64_Addr    st_value;       /* Symbol value */
  Elf64_Xword   st_size;        /* Symbol size */
} Elf64_Sym;

Updated MCVE
Here is a MCVE that shows my problem (and thanks to @user12002570 for pointing out that my previous MCVE wasn't correct):
file.hpp
#ifndef FILE_HPP
#define FILE_HPP

#include <stdint.h>

struct Elf64_Sym;

uint64_t getSize(Elf64_Sym * ptr);

#endif

file.cpp
#include "file.hpp"
#include <elf.h>

uint64_t getSize(Elf64_Sym * ptr)
{
    return ptr->st_size;
}

You can try to compile it using the following command line g++ -c file.cpp and you will receive the following error:
/usr/include/elf.h:538:3: error: conflicting declaration 'typedef struct Elf64_Sym Elf64_Sym'
  538 | } Elf64_Sym;
      |   ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from file.cpp:1:
file.hpp:6:8: note: previous declaration as 'struct Elf64_Sym'
    6 | struct Elf64_Sym;
      |        ^~~~~~~~~

Do you have a solution that would allow a forward declaration of the Elf64_Sym structure in C++?
And for completeness sake here is the definition of this struct in <elf.h>:
typedef struct
{
  Elf64_Word    st_name;        /* Symbol name (string tbl index) */
  unsigned char st_info;        /* Symbol type and binding */
  unsigned char st_other;       /* Symbol visibility */
  Elf64_Section st_shndx;       /* Section index */
  Elf64_Addr    st_value;       /* Symbol value */
  Elf64_Xword   st_size;        /* Symbol size */
} Elf64_Sym;


Can you change elf.h contents?

I would also recommend asking a new separate question for your follow up/real question with a real mcve so that already posted answer don't get invalidated.

The edited question invalidates the already posted answer. It would've been better to create a new question or atleast add your edit at the end of your question. I've edited the question to include the edit at the end of your question so that the already posted answer doesn't get invalidated.

To answer your question, just change the function declaration touint64_t getSize(struct Elf64_Sym * ptr);. Note the struct in the first parameter. Then remove struct Elf64_Sym; in the header file.hpp. Then finally remove #include "file.hpp" from the source file file.cpp. See demo in my answer.

If you need a forward declaration of a typedef struct, you can declare an empty struct and then typedef it eg
struct _Elf64Sym;
typedef _Elf64Sym Elf64_Sym;

So long as the second typedef is defined identically, a second typedef of the same struct will compile.
If the typedef is of an anonymous struct, you need to give the struct a name. If you can't rename the struct in the other header file, you're out of options.

Note that all names starting with underscore followed by a capital letter are reserved for the implementation. You are not allowed to use such names in your own code.

@SmellyCat Thank you for your response. I indeed can't rename the struct in this header so as you said I'm out of options for a forward declaration and will have to do an explicit include in the header file.

 Answer to edited question 
These are the steps to solve the issue.
Step 1
You can just comment out #include "file.hpp" from the source file file.cpp.
Step 2
In the header file.hpp remove the forward declaration struct Elf64_Sym.
Step 3
In the header file.hpp change the function declaration to:
//---------------vvvvvv--------------------->used struct here
uint64_t getSize(struct Elf64_Sym * ptr);

Working demo
 Answer to old question 

Do you have a solution that would allow a forward declaration of the Elf64_Sym structure in C++?

You don't need to write struct Elf64_Sym in the source file at all since you're already including its header which has the required typedef.
You can directly create an object of type Elf64_Sym by writing:
Elf64_Sym object;

in the source file.
Working demo

Method 2
If you're allowed to modify the header elf.h then a more c++ way of writing the struct would be without the typedef:
//no need for typedef here
 struct Elf64_Sym
{
  Elf64_Word    st_name;        /* Symbol name (string tbl index) */
  unsigned char st_info;        /* Symbol type and binding */
  unsigned char st_other;       /* Symbol visibility */
  Elf64_Section st_shndx;       /* Section index */
  Elf64_Addr    st_value;       /* Symbol value */
  Elf64_Xword   st_size;        /* Symbol size */
} ;

Then you could write struct Elf64_Stm; in the source file without any problem.
Demo

Thank you for your response but the fact that I forward declare in a .cpp file is just for the example. In the actual code the forward declaration is done in a header file. And to answer your question: no I can't modify elf.h as it is part of an external library.

@Forbinn I see. So the answer works for you current given mcve. I will try to see if I can come up with an answer for ]your other case. Btw, in you actual code in the header where you wrote struct Elf64_Sym you're not including the elf.h right? because otherwise you would not have needed the forward declaring in the first place. Btw this is exactly we recommend posting real code as a [mcve]. You're welcome.

Yeah, that is my bad, I took the minimal a bit to its extreme here. But no I do not include <elf.h> otherwise the forward declaration would be useless.

@Forbinn Also if you're not including the header elf.h in your other header then there should be no error. See working demo. In the demo you'll see that the source file doesn't include elf.h just like your other header and in the source file struct Elf64_Sym; works without any error. So I think the given question is answered.

Ok, I see were the confusion come from. Let me update the question with an example closer to my use-case as you suggested

@Forbinn But that will invalidate my answer. I'll recommend asking a new separate question with a new mcve that shows your actual issue/problem.

@Forbinn To answer your question, just change the function declaration touint64_t getSize(struct Elf64_Sym * ptr);. Note the struct in the first parameter. Then remove struct Elf64_Sym; in the header file.hpp. Then finally remove #include "file.hpp" from the source file file.cpp. See demo my updated answer.
